# Should I round values before inserting into integer column?

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine a very trivial table that contains only one column, which is an **INTEGER**.

Now, to insert something into this table I do something along the lines of:

```
$val = 11 / 5;  // 2.2

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ($val)');
$stmt->execute();
```

I know that this will be rounded as it is inserted into the table (I've tried it), though I am not exactly sure if this is done by PHP or at the Database.

**Question:**

Should I really round my value in PHP before inserting it?

```
$val = round(11 / 5);  // 2
```

Comment: I'd say that depends entirely on whether or not it makes sense to round given the purpose of the table.

Comment: You don't *have* to.  MySQL will convert the value to an integer.

Comment: You may want to keep its raw value, it may prove useful later on. You can always round it off later via query and/or PHP.

Comment: If you didn't do a `round()` in PHP, when you just leave it as it is `2.2`. When that particular data is inserted to a data type `INT`. It will be inserted, but upon insertion, it will be truncated (`.2`).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know I don't need to - I've tried it - question is concerning whether there is any reason that I should round explicitly in my PHP code rather than relying on MySQL?

Comment: @Ghost does MySQL truncate (which would give similar behaviour to rounding down), or does MySQL round() in a similar fashion to PHP's function by default?

Comment: @adey_888 . . . That begs the question of why you want to put a floating point value into an integer field.  I suppose you should really fix that problem.

Comment: @adey_888 yeah why do you want to insert a float inside a column int? anyway, when you put `2.4` it inserts `2`, when you put `2.9`, it inserts `3`

Comment: just a quick note of reference so that future readers can be clear: truncating is only the same value of rounding for values where the value would be rounding down. E.G. `round(2.4) = truncate(2.4) = 2`, but for values that would round up, it is totally different: `round(2.7) = 3, truncate(2.7)=2`

Comment: Storing as integer as there is no need to store decimal places for this value. Seems absurd to round the value each time I select it before presenting to the users. Doesn't it make more sense to round it once and store it as an int? I'm asking if I should round it in PHP or let MySQL do it.